# How to redirect after create action in SF2 controller

Tags: redirect, symfony, routes

Here is the action that is not working properly, The entity is created but i'm always rendering the AileronsFrontendBundle:Default:observation.html.twig

As the code shows, this createAction should render my home template, but the template rendering is not the good one.

```
 /**
 * Creates a new Observation entity.
 *
 * @Route("/observation/new", name="observation_create")
 * @Method("POST")
 * @Template("AileronsFrontendBundle:Default:observation.html.twig")
 */
public function createAction(Request $request) {
    $entity = new Observation();
    $form = $this->createForm(new ObservationType(), $entity);
    $form->bind($request);


    if ($form->isValid()) {
        $entity->getObservator()->setIp($request->getClientIp());
        $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
        $em->persist($entity);
        $em->flush();

        $msg = array(
            'type'=>'success',
            'title'=>'Merci !',
            'text'=>'Votre observation à bien été enregistré, merci pour votre participation !',
        );
        $this->redirect($this->generateUrl('home', array('msg'=>$msg)));
    }

    return array(
        'entity' => $entity,
        'form' => $form->createView(),
    );
```

Insted of redirect i've tried this:

```
$this->render('AileronsFrontendBundle:Default:index.html.twig', array('msg'=>$msg));
```

It is not working too.

Here is my index action

```
/**
 * @Route("/", name="home")
 * @Template()
 */
public function indexAction() {
    return array();
}
```

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: This createAction should render my home template, but the template rendering is not the good one. I'm alway rendering AileronsFrontendBundle:Default:observation.html.twig

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to *return* your redirect.

```
return $this->redirect($this->generateUrl('home', array('msg'=>$msg)));
```

An action always needs to *return* a response object.
Example with returning a rendered Twig file:

```
return $this->render('AcmeTestBundle:Test:test.html.twig', array());
```

Comment: What a shame ! Why im I not seeing that ! Thanks to point this out